# Show only attachment link in mailkit imap

Tags: c#, .net, imap, gmail-imap, mailkit

I just want to display the links of attachments to download in mail body without downloading the attachment initially. coz i don't want to download and save the attachments on my server everytime.

when users clicks the link, then I want to download that particular attachment(s) from gmail server ("https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/u/1/?xxxx-xxxx")

is there is anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

MailKit does not provide any way of doing this because it's not something that IMAP supports.

That said, it might be possible to figure out how to construct the URL based on the properties of the MIME attachment.

Based on examining the Download link in one of my own emails, it looks like Google uses their `X-Attachment-Id` header value to construct the `realattid` portion of the url. They probably have other variables as well, but it's hard to know exactly where the other values come from.

The `attid` value in the download url appears to be a positional value of the MIME attachment in the tree, similar to MailKit's `BodyPart.PartSpecifier` string.

Instead of trying to recreate GMail's download link, you could always use MailKit's [`ImapFolder.GetBodyPart()`](http://www.mimekit.org/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_MailFolder_GetBodyPart.htm) API to download individual MIME parts when the user requests them.

In order to take advantage of this API, you'll need to call [`ImapFolder.Fetch()`](http://www.mimekit.org/docs/html/Overload_MailKit_MailFolder_Fetch.htm) with `MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure`.

You can take a look at https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/samples/ImapClientDemo/ImapClientDemo/MainWindow.cs to see how to use the `MessageSummary.Body`property that you get back from the `Fetch` request.